# How can I convert an image into Base64 string and save to text file using classic ASP/VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I've been stuck on this one for a few days.
Using classic ASP, I need to take an uploaded .JPG/.PNG file and base64 encode it so that I can send it to a Java web service.
Here's what I have so far:

```
Function convertImageToBase64(filePath)
  'response.write(Server.MapPath("\") & "<br>")
  dim fs,f
  set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  set f=fs.CreateTextFile(Server.MapPath("\") &"\Upload\5566.txt",true)
  
  Dim inputStream
  Set inputStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
  inputStream.Open
  inputStream.Type = 1  ' adTypeBinary
  inputStream.LoadFromFile filePath
  Dim bytes: bytes = inputStream.Read
  Dim dom: Set dom = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
  Dim elem: Set elem = dom.createElement("tmp")
  elem.dataType = "bin.base64"
  elem.nodeTypedValue = bytes
  convertImageToBase64 = "data:image/png;base64," & Replace(elem.text, vbLf, "")

  f.write(convertImageToBase64)
  set f=nothing
  set fs=nothing
  f.close
  
  End Function

convertImageToBase64(RootPath&"/upload/"&Rs("FileName"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to read the file into a variable before you encode it.

http://eddiejackson.net/wp/?p=8619

```
Set objFileToRead = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(RootPath&"/upload/"&Rs("FileName"),1)
strFileText = objFileToRead.ReadAll()
objFileToRead.Close
Set objFileToRead = Nothing

Base64String = convertImageToBase64(strFileText)
```